# On the convergence rate of $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\{x^n+x^{-n}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractional-part, equidistribution

Let
$$S:=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n} \{x^n+x^{-n} \}<+\infty\right\}\\
S':=S\cap(1,+\infty)$$

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497050/on-the-convergence-of-sum-frac-lognn-xnx-n) post it was proved that $\mu(S)=0$, thanks to the equidistribution of $\{x^n\}$.

Trying to understand a little bit more about the structure of $S'$ (from which the structure of $S$ follows thanks to the map $x\to \frac{1}{x}$, under which the series is invariant), I noticed the following:

Note that the related series $\sum \{x^n+x^{-n}\}^2$ converges iff $x$ is a [P.V. number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number).

Thus, we now know that the set of P.V. numbers is contained in $S'$. The natural question, now, is whether the converse implication holds, i.e. if $\{x: x \ \text{is a P.V. number}\}=S'$.

If this were true, it would imply the longstanding problem of whether the convergence of $\sum \{x^n\}$ is enough to determine if $x$ is a p.v. number. 
However, since our "test for p.v.-ness" is weaker, it may be easier to find a counterexample

Comment: Do the braces indicate fractional part?

Comment: @martycohen yes